# How do I encode a URL param as its inserted in a URl looking like /abc/:param/def?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5, urlencode

I'm Rails 5.  What's the proper way to encode a param so that it can be inserted into a route that looks like

```
/books/:param/action
```

I tried this

```
let(:url_encoded_param) { "abc.def-ghi.xyz" }
```

But it doesn't encode anything and the resulting route

```
/books/abc.def-ghi.xyz/action
```

results in a

```
No route matches [GET] "/books/abc.def-ghi.xyz/action"
```

error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the desired output is, but you could do something similar to this: https://www.urlencoder.net/ruby-url-encode. Since you have added the Rails tag to your question I assume you have access to `ERB`, so this should work:

```
require 'erb'
include ERB::Util

let(:url_encoded_param) { url_encode("abc.def-ghi.xyz".gsub('.', '')) }
```

The `gsub` is there because `encode` doesn't remove or convert the periods. The periods will break the URL every time, so you'll have to substitute them manually (in this case via `gsub`). It might be wise to remove all non-alphanumeric characters to be save, which can be done with `gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')`
Then in a spec you could do something like:

`get :your_action, params: { some_param: url_encoded_param }`

That would theoretically work with the route:

`GET /books/:some_param/your_action`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  It doesn't convert ".", which is ultimately what is screwing up the Rails' RESTful path resolution.

Comment: Yeah, the dot will screw up any URL. What's your desired output?